# Use same terminal session across the devices when using vscode-remote ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmux, vscode-remote

I'm using three of the devices to develop. Desktop(Home), MacBook(Work), Laptop(Remote).

I'm developing a web project that needs to build and API server. So I'm running build steps and API server using watch parameter.

However, If I do work at remote or home, I can't start API server because that port already bound by other process that executed by work MacBook terminal. I tried to kill that process, but It restored automatically by watch parameter.

So now I want to use the same terminal session across the multiple devices. I thought maybe I can do this using tmux, but I don't know is there a better solution for this.

Is there available something to do this in vscode-server? Or just I need to use tmux or other solution?

Comment: Configuring that API server to use a different (free) port?

Comment: @DevSolar sadly it uses static port.